# How can I send a file to myself using Skype?

Tags: skype

I have Skype running on two (Windows) computers using the same account. I would like to transfer a file from one computer to another computer using Skype file transfer, but I can't start a chat with myself. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The only one I know that can do what you want is telegram

Comment: As of 2023 (Skype desktop version 8.100) you can chat with yourself. There is the contact/chat "You" pinned under favorites. Just open it and type (or share files) away.

Answer (score 32):

You can start a new group chat and do not invite anyone then send your text/file to the conversation.
This is what I just did to quickly transfer a file between my two devices.

Comment: I cannot start a conversion without inviting anyone!

Comment: I am still using old skype and it's still doable. Thanks!

Comment: You can still do this, but you have to create a "new group chat" for it to work. If you just create a "new chat" it will make you choose someone. Once you create a "new group chat" you can give it a name and then it will always be available for you to continue using so you don't have to create a new one every time.

Answer (score 13):

I found solution.

It works for me on Linux Skype 8.22.0.2

You can create New Group. 
Type the name of it. 
Choose one persone from your contacts. 
Create the group.
After that just remove one persone, who you added.

And you will be alone in chat and still can write messages. 
Now you will be only one persone, who can see messages in this room.

Comment: You just can create a new Group with [Ctrl]+[N] without any person other than yourself, At least in my setting (Win10 Skype 7.41.0.101)

Comment: @yunzen Mine makes me add another user when I use ctrl-n. But it works when I try to create a new group chat as ruby_dev says. I think we could need the shortcut for creating a new "group" chat in order for your suggestion to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that. In both computers, start a chat with someone who is not online. (Preferably use a contact who you know will not be available or use another account of your own.) When you type into the chat in one computer, you will see the text also in the other computer.

If you drag a file to the chat in one computer, you can download it in the other computer. At least I can and I don't have the "download files automatically" option switched on.

Comment: Using two accounts seems like a much better idea than sharing your file with somebody and hoping they don't log in while it's available to them!

Comment: agreed. Actually I used another non-used account of my own in both computers. It just saved me the trouble of logging out and in with another account and then again out and then again in with my main account.

Comment: Definitively it is better to send to another account of your own. Some of your contact  can be _hidden_ in _skype_ . It means __you will not know if a user is really offline or just in the hidden status__ until you send the file. BTW It works fine between linux and android devices too.

Comment: Why not email it to yourself?

Comment: Or use file sharing?

Comment: @DavidPostill, basically because the ease of doing it... move file from laptop to home computer on the same table. Steps: 1 Grab laptop's mouse. 2. Drag file to chat window. 3. Grap desktop PC's mouse. 4) Click the file icon in chat window to open the file in the desktop. Extremely simple especially when both computers are already running Skype. Is there a simpler method? With this method I don't even need to touch the keyboard, no need to log into any websites, and both computers can be company computers whose settings you can't change. All that is needed is Skype running on both...

Answer (score 3):

Another excellent way is to run OneNote on every device, that lets you easily display links and documents wherever you choose.

Comment: This is an answer. Not the most relevant one either, but it is a possible solution.

Comment: not an answer to the question (skype to yourself)

Answer (score 2):

It is just as easy using [Dropbox](https://db.tt/ExdsNwlE) (note: this is my referral link which will grant both you and I bonus storage, if you want to sign up without the referral then go to the [main Dropbox page](https://www.dropbox.com/)). There is no need to go to websites to share files or touch the keyboard since these seem to be your concerns.

Install dropbox on both the computers and login with the same dropbox account to both.

Then the file sharing process will be :

1. Drag the file into the folder linked to DropBox on one computer.
2. File will automatically appear on the other computers folder that is linked to Dropbox.

With this method:

1. You additionally have a backup of the files kept on the cloud. (no need to think about backing up files)
2. Also, if a file is overwritten or deleted, you can always get the file back with dropbox's automatically managed version history

Comment: possible, but not the answer to the question (i.e. skype to yourself)

Comment: yes, not a direct answer. but it is an alternate (and more common) solution to accomplish the same thing (transferring files between 2 PCs that you own via some service)

Answer (score 2):

Look for "Untitled conversation" in Skype and you can chat with yourself there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Make 2 accounts and open one on each computer.  This photo was sent to self over Skype. :)